# How to restart in live cd persistence?

Tags: live-cd, testing

I installed a daily build 12.10 on my Mac to test livecd.  I already had a pen drive formatted to ext3 labeled casper-rw.

I had to invoke the "other options" with the F6 button so that I could append "persistent", but it didn't work.  I clicked "try ubuntu," started browsing the web, and did a restart. When I ran the liveCD again, the persistence failed.

How can I restart in liveCD persistence?  Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can as you would need the OS to constantly wright your data to the cd whitch just would not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized that I press the enter key at the initial bootup screen.  When I press F6, it shows me not only a menu but also a boot commandline.

By appending the word "persistent" at the end of the line and going on to "Try Ubuntu," I'm immediately directed to the desktop environment. I browse the web, change some settings, and prepare to test persistence.

I restart again, press F6 - essentially repeat the same process - and I'm directed to the persistence session.